A321XLR pair of bulges on the belly
What are these two elements of A321XLR? Are they structural elements or something else?


They are not present in A321 or A321neo models:

Pics credits: Nathan Walkowiak (CC-BY), Jean-Pierre Nivet (CC-BY), Clemens Vasters (CC-BY)

It's the fuel pump fairing for the Rear Center Tank which is only there in the A321 XLR.
There's one on the underside of the wings too (on both A320 and A321, neo or XLR)
The round bulge at the root is what connects this wiring to the fuel pump which is connected to the tank and the two "rods" are covers for the wiring of these fuel pumps. They are outside to prevent ignition sources.
Image of this thing in the A320ceo

I believe it's the same thing but it looks different in the A321 XLR.
